# jupyter notebook / lab as a library

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to run a jupyter kernel server and a web frontend independently to embed jupyter in a custom website? Let me explain with an example. I'd like to write a python script like this, using some imaginary jupyter library:

```
import jupyter

def hello():
    print("hello")

jupyter_server = jupyter.PythonKernelServer()
jupyter_server.run(port=1234)
```

Then, I'd like to write this piece of javascript to embed a jupyter frontend in my website, using some imaginary jupyter node library:

```
const jupyter = require("jupyter");

let frontend = new jupyter.Frontend();
document.body.appendChild(frontend.domElement);
frontend.connect("ws://localhost:1234");
frontend.insertCell({
    "cmd": "hello()"
})
```

Hopefully the scripts are self-explanatory. Does jupyter provide isolated enough components to achieve something like this?